# How to clean up event listener inside useCallback

Tags: reactjs, react-usecallback

```
const ref = useCallback((node) => {
 if (node) {
  // ...intersection observer code goes here
 }
}, []);

return <div ref={ref} />
```

I use `useCallback` hook to setup intersection observer listener once `ref`'s node is available. My question is what is the correct way to kill intersection observer when component unmounts?

Comment: Could you share this _intersection observer code_?

Answer (score -1):

move your listeners to useEffect hook